# How can I check for the least value in a 2D array?

Tags: c++, arrays

`#include <iostream>`

```
using namespace std;
```

`const int rows = 2;`

`const int cols = 3;`

> **THIS FUNCTION PRINTS OUT THE ELEMENTS THAT WERE ENTERED FROM THE USER**
>
> ***2** ROWS BY **3** COLUMNS*

`void Output(int x[][cols], int rows){`

```
int r = 0, c = 0, min = 0;

for (r = 0; r < rows; ++r){
    cout << "ROW # " << r + 1 << ": ";
    for (c = 0; c < cols; ++c)
        cout << x[r][c] << " ";
    cout << endl;
}
```

`}`

> **THIS FUNCTION WILL CHECK FOR LEAST VALUES (WHICH IS WHERE I NEED HELP WITH)**
>
> **2** ROWS BY **3** COLUMNS

`void CheckLeast(int x[][cols], int rows){`

```
int r = 0, c = 0, min = 1;
for (r = 0; r < rows; ++r){
    for (c = 0; c < cols; ++c){
        if (x[r][c] < x[r+1][c+1]){
            min = x[r][c];
            cout << "Least value is: " << min;
            cout << endl;
        }
        }
        min = 0;
}
```

`}`

> **MAIN OF THE PROGRAM HAS NO PROBLEMS AT ALL..**

`int main(){`

```
int r = 0, c = 0, x[rows][cols];
for (r = 0; r < rows; ++r){
    for (c = 0; c < cols; ++c){
        cout << "Enter a value: ";
        cin >> x[r][c];
        system("cls");
    }
}
Output(x, 2);
CheckLeast(x, 2);
cout << "\n\n\n\n";
system("pause");
return 0;
```

`}`

Comment: Why don't you just write the `CheckLeast` function , where you're having problem ?

Comment: Well yea i should've done that from the first, but anyway CheckLeast function is the problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you are checking for the least value in each row.

If this is so, then try the following:

```
int r = 0, c = 0, min;
for (r = 0; r < rows; ++r){
    min = x[r][0]; // initialize
    for (c = 0; c < cols; ++c){
        if (x[r][c] < min){
            min = x[r][c];
        }
    }
    cout << "Least value is: " << min;
    cout << endl;
}
```

If you want the least value in the entire matrix, then initialize min before the loops and just output it after exiting the outer loop.

```
int r = 0, c = 0, min;
min = x[0][0];
for (r = 0; r < rows; ++r){
    for (c = 0; c < cols; ++c){
        if (x[r][c] < min){
            min = x[r][c];
        }
    }
}
cout << "Least value is: " << min;
cout << endl;
```

Comment: Glad it helped. Hope you have understood the logic.

Comment: well, in the first one, I didnt understand why min = x[r][0] and not x[r][c] since c is set to 0 already from the first place

Comment: The logic is that you initialize min to be 1st element of the row ([r][0]). Then you scan the row and check if any element is smaller than min, then update min accordingly. You can very well start the loop for c from 1 instead of 0 since there is no point checking min with itself..

Comment: same thing to the next code that does check for the entire matrix, why is min set to min = x[0][0]

Comment: @user3104111 You need to initialize min to some value before start comparing it with elements in the matrix. So the first element is a valid candidate for initialization.

Comment: One last question mate, how can I get the least value per columns for example

1 2 3
4 5 6

1 is less than 4
2 is less than 5
3 is less than 6

Comment: Simply exchange the inner and outer loops, i.e., make the outer loop as the column loop (c) and inner loop as row loop (r).

Comment: I tried exchanging them but it seems that the the first two values will be duplicated automatically

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to access elements beyond the end of the array, r+1 and c+1 will go past the bounds of the array on the final iterations of the loops. You should just compare the current element (`x[r][c]`) directly to `min` each time.

You also seem to be printing `cout << "Least value is: " << min;` every time that `(x[r][c] < x[r+1][c+1])` evaluates to true. You should put that outside of both of the loops.

So my loop would be something like

```
int r = 0, c = 0, min = x[0][0];
for (r = 0; r < rows; ++r){
    for (c = 0; c < cols; ++c){
        if (x[r][c] < min){
            min = x[r][c];
    }
}
cout << "Least value is: " << min;
cout << endl;
```

Comment: Hmmm that doesn't make any sense to me :S ... If I should put my if ..... code outside the loop, then the program will do nothing

Comment: No no no, you should put the `cout` outside of the loop, unless you want to to print that every time that min gets reassigned. Also, do you want the lowest value in the whole 2-d array?

Comment: Yea for the whole array but by rows for now

Comment: You can do both, but you need a 2 variables. 1 for overall, and 1 for the lowest in the row.